# how to test if a postgres partition has been populated or not

Tags: postgresql, performance

How can I (quickly) test if a postgres partition has any rows in it?

I have a partitioned postgres table 'TABLE_A', partitioned by date-range. The name of each individual partition indicates the date-range i.e. TABLE_A_20220101 (1st Jan this year) TABLE_A_20220102 (2nd Jan 2022)

The table includes many years of data, so it includes several thousand individual partitions, each partition contains many millions of rows.

Is there a *quick* way of testing if a partition has any data in it? There are several solutions I've found, but they all involve `count(*)` and all take ages.

Please note - I'm NOT trying to accurately determine the row-count, just determine if each partition has any rows in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `exists` condition:

```
select exists (select * from partition_name limit 1)
```

That will return `true` if `partition_name` contains at least one row